# How to add another scroll view on a collection view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a collection view controller in storyboard that I can display images on the collection view. But now I want to add a scroll view above the collection view to show different information.
I've tried dragging the scroll view from the library directly, but it does not work.

Could someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CollectionViewController is what it is, it controlls the collection view. What you actually need is a controller with collection view and a scroll view. Make a UIViewController, add a collection view and a scroll view, connect the delegates and outlets and voila.